# Helm variables used at custom places

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am not able to reference variable inside a nested variable in Helm. Also, I am not able to do this as nested reference. I want to retrieve all client variables under client name using the value of the client_name variable. How can I do that?

**Values.yaml**

```
clients:
  client1:
    incomigBucket: databucket
    outgoingBucket: tempbucket
    webURL: http://example.com
  client2: 
     incomingBucket: databucket
    outgoingBucket: tempbucket
    webURL: http://example.com
```

I want to store client variables values in one variable and want to use it at different places in my Json file. if I use range function then it create section twice(as I have mentioned 2 clients), is there any thing in Helm I can use which can store these variables dynamically and use it in custom places in json file?

Sample File Section:

```
 "FileConfig": {
         "Client1": {
           "incomingLocationPath": "s3://{{ .Values.clients.client1.incomingBucket }}/dir1/dir2",
           "outgoingLocationPath": "s3://{{ .Values.clients.client1.outgoingBucket }}/dir1/dir2",
         },
         "Client2": {
           "incomingLocationPath": "s3://{{ .Values.clients.client2.incomingBucket }}/dir1/dir2",
           "outgoingLocationPath": "s3://{{ .Values.clients.client2.outgoingBucket }}/dir1/dir2",
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure where you intend to use this snippet. I assume it is inside a `configMap`. At least,  I am not aware of any resource that had `FileConfig` section. I wouldn't know why it should be JSON either.

The basic pattern could look like this.

```yaml
fileConfig:
  {{- range $client, $config := .Values.clients }}
  {{ $client }}:
    incomingLocationPath: "s3://{{ $config.incomingBucket }}/dir1/dir2"
    outgoingLocationPath: "s3://{{ $config.outgoingBucket }}/dir1/dir2"
  {{- end }}
```

In something like a configMap to create JSON it could look like this.

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: file-config-json
data:
  config.json: |
    "fileConfig": {
      {{- range $client, $config := .Values.clients }}
      "{{ $client }}": {
        "incomingLocationPath": "s3://{{ $config.incomingBucket }}/dir1/dir2",
        "outgoingLocationPath": "s3://{{ $config.outgoingBucket }}/dir1/dir2"
      }
      {{- end }}
    }
```